# python sqlite3 statement not being run/not doing anything

Tags: python, sqlite, discord.py

I don't understand why my statement isn't running, it seems that it should. I have checked the docs to make sure my formatting is correct, I also changed the `UPDATE` to delete which gave no results. 
This is my table schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE shop(
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    poster_id TEXT,
    item_name TEXT,
    price TEXT,
    item_id TEXT,
    sold TEXT
    );
```

this is my statement (that via debugging I know gets run):

```
c.execute('''UPDATE shop SET sold = ? WHERE item_id = ?''',('True',message.split()[0]))
```

which does not work
however for debugging I've tried:

```
c.execute('''SELECT * FROM shop WHERE item_id = ?''',(message.split()[0],))
```

which outputted exactly as expected.

Comment: did you create a DB? `conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')`

Comment: What data type is `sold`? Sqlite doesn't have a boolean storage class.

Comment: yes i have created the db and its TEXT as said in the schema

Comment: in that case it would give an unsupported type error surely, im passing the value "True" in it, so i am passing it text.

Comment: No write access maybe.

Comment: @Wups i do a similar thing to the same database file in a different table that works fine so cant be that

Comment: Are you running `connection.commit()` after your ``update`` statement? This is not needed for `select`, which could explain why one works & the other doesn't. Commit is needed for `update` & `delete` to push changes to your db.

Comment: @stijndcl yep this was the problem i had written `conn.close()` twice by accident. Thanks for waking me up lol

Comment: Alright, I'll add it as an answer to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UPDATE` & `DELETE` statements require you to use `connection.commit()` in order to commit the changes to the db, which is why the `SELECT` statement worked but the other two didn't.